# Add hide for all other buttons in functions jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

Could someone please help me to add the command hide for all the other buttons, in that function. Because in this function I can put several buttons on the same page without having to deuterated the function.

```js
var d = document;
function trclick(a){
  var b=a.id,view,valbt;
  var c=$("#bd_"+b);
  var e=d.getElementById('nod_'+b);
  view=c.css('display');
  c.toggle('slow');
  valbt=(view=='none'?'[-]':'[+]');
  e.innerHTML=valbt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <button id="look1" onclick="trclick(this);" style="font-size: 11px; cursor: pointer;"><span id="nod_look1">[+]</span>Look1</button>
  <div id="bd_look1" style="border: 0px inset; margin: 0px; padding: 6px; display: none;">
    HELLO
  </div><br />
  
  <button id="look2" onclick="trclick(this);" style="font-size: 11px; cursor: pointer;"><span id="nod_look2">[+]</span>Look2</button>
  <div id="bd_look2" style="border: 0px inset; margin: 0px; padding: 6px; display: none;">
    HELLO
  </div><br />
  
  <button id="look3" onclick="trclick(this);" style="font-size: 11px; cursor: pointer;"><span id="nod_look3">[+]</span>Look3</button>
  <div id="bd_look3" style="border: 0px inset; margin: 0px; padding: 6px; display: none;">
    HELLO
  </div>  
</center>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class (Ex: "bd") for the content divs and always hide them before showing the current one. The same for the [+] / [-] spans.

```js
var d = document;
function trclick(a){
  var b=a.id,view,valbt;
  var c=$("#bd_"+b);
  $(".bd").hide(100); //hide all first
  $(".nod").html('[+]'); //reset labels to [+]
  c.toggle('slow'); //it could be c.show('slow')
  $("#nod_"+b).html('[-]'); //current label to [-]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
  <button id="look1" onclick="trclick(this);" style="font-size: 11px; cursor: pointer;"><span class="nod" id="nod_look1">[+]</span>Look1</button>
  <div id="bd_look1" class="bd" style="border: 0px inset; margin: 0px; padding: 6px; display: none;">
    HELLO
  </div><br />
  
  <button id="look2" onclick="trclick(this);" style="font-size: 11px; cursor: pointer;"><span class="nod" id="nod_look2">[+]</span>Look2</button>
  <div id="bd_look2" class="bd" style="border: 0px inset; margin: 0px; padding: 6px; display: none;">
    HELLO
  </div><br />
  
  <button id="look3" onclick="trclick(this);" style="font-size: 11px; cursor: pointer;"><span class="nod" id="nod_look3">[+]</span>Look3</button>
  <div id="bd_look3" class="bd" style="border: 0px inset; margin: 0px; padding: 6px; display: none;">
    HELLO
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: I've fixed the code. There is no need to switch bewteen [+] and [-] labels.

Comment: thanks for the help, just needed to add the command "not ()".